# prevent firestore number from going nevgative?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm New to firestore. I need a little help.

I got a function, that updates the amount of "stock shares". its a "sell" function, so the amount can only go down.

The problem is. I don't wanna go below 0.

So I wanna get the PREVIOUS amount of shares. before I update to the new amount.
So I can make sure I don't go below 0.

There are 2 ways to do this. 1 is by using firestore rules, 2 is by getting the Prev amount like i said.

Can you guys help me get the Prev amount before the UPDATE stage?
code:

```
function sellStock(){
    db.collection("Stocks")
    .where("ticker", "==", props.name)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if(!querySnapshot.empty){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
            db.collection("myStocks")
            .doc(doc.id)
            .update({
                shares: doc.data().shares - amount
            })
```

"shares" will be the prev amount.
"amount" will be the amount of shares we wanna sell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
.update({
            shares: (doc.data().shares - amount) >= 0 ? (doc.data().shares - amount) : 0
       })
```

Comment: yes man. thats it. thank you! should have thought about it.
cant accept the answer in the first few mins, ill accept it soon

Answer (score 1):

*Updated after discussion in the comments.*

There is an important aspect to consider with your business logic: Do you need to execute an atomic operation on several documents? Example: You are subtracting the value of amount to the value of shares, since it is a selling operation but I guess that somewhere else (in another document) you are also adding some value, for example in the bank account of the seller.

In such a case you should use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#transactions): "if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction". You need to include in the Transaction all the documents that need to be locked while the operation is ongoing (i.e. all the docs that are involved in the operation, the ones on which you subtract and the ones on which you add).

However, since you want to update several documents, returned by a query, you cannot use a Transaction of one of the mobile/web SDKs (e.g. iOS, Android, Web/JavaScript), because the mobile/web SDKs use [optimistic concurrency controls to resolve data contention](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention?authuser=0#data_contention_in_the_mobileweb_sdks).

What you can do is to use one of the Admin SDKs, like the Node.js one, since it uses pessimistic concurrency controls and therefore offers the possibility to run a [Transaction **on a query**](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get) (see that you can pass a query to the `get()` method).  So you could do that in a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?authuser=0).

Here is an example of a Transaction that will atomically update all the docs on which you substract. Since you didn't share the entire business logic (we don't know which are the docs that you need to update by adding a value) it's a bit difficult to go deeper in the example.

```
exports.updateTickers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    // get the value of the filter (i.e. props.name) via the data Object
    const filter = data.filter;
    const amount = data.amount;

    const db = admin.firestore();
    return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        let queryRef = db.collection("Stocks").where("ticker", "==", filter);
        return transaction.get(queryRef)
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const currentValue = doc.get('amount');
                    if (currentValue - amount > 0) (
                        transaction.update(doc.ref, { likes: currentValue - amount })
                    )
                });
            });
    })
        .then(() => {
            return { result: "Amounts update successful" }
        })

});
```

Comment: thank you guys for these detailed comments. it is very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome @bigLezo. There is an important aspect to consider with your business logic: do you need to execute an atomic operation **on several documents**? Example: You are subtracting the value of amount to the value of shares, since it is a selling operation but I guess that somewhere else (in another document) you are also adding some value, for example in the bank account of the seller. Can you confirm if this is the case or you just wan tto updta individual documents.

Comment: you are correct. there is both "selling" and "buying" options. each of them do update the document every time the user use it. what do you recommend??

Comment: I then recommend using a Transaction as I explained in my answer: you need to include in the transaction all the documents that need to be locked while the operation is ongoing (i.e. all the docs that are involved in the operation).

Answer (score 0):

The only sure-fire way to prevent the `shares` count from going below 0 is to enforce that in security rules:

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.shares >= 0;
```

Any other method can be bypassed by a malicious user who uses *your* project configuration data with *their* code.

---

With this in place, the simplest (and fastest) way to subtract the `amount` from the `shares` count is with an [atomic increment operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value):

```
db.collection("myStocks")
  .doc(doc.id)
  .update({
      shares: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1 * amount)
  })
```